# JSON structure string in groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I wanted to create a string in groovy in following structure

```
"{\"Changes\": [{\"Action\": \"UPSERT\", \"ResourceRecordSet\": 
       { \"Name\": \"rms-collector-demo.cnqr.delivery.\",\"Type\": 
         \"CNAME\",\"TTL\": 300,\"ResourceRecords\": [{ \"Value\": 
         \"d-4kushcom5y13.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\"}]}}]}"
```

tried with escaping characters but was not useful. can some one help what should be the format used in groovy to define this string.

Comment: You can use multiline string enclosed between either `'''` or `"""` (three quotes). What is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy supports multi-line strings, so you can simply use

```
"""
   {"Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": 
   { "Name": "rms-collector-demo.cnqr.delivery.","Type": 
     "CNAME","TTL": 300,"ResourceRecords": [{ "Value": 
     "d-4kushcom5y13.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"}]}}]}
"""
```

You can also use `'''` to create a normal String.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of carefully crafting some JSON as a string (and maybe add errors in the process), you can use `JsonOutput` to create the JSON from a simple data structure:

```
def json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([Changes: ["X"]])
println json
// => {"Changes":["X"]}
```